# Ошибка в Python 3.7.9 (Thonny 3.3.13) - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал код на питоне, складывающий и умножающий числа из одного файла и записывающий результат в другой.

```
fin = open('input.txt', 'r')
p = fin.read().split()
a, b = map(int, p)
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
fout.write(str(a + b)+'\n')
fout.write(str(a * b))
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

При компиляции выдаёт ошибку:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

Comment: Значит `map(int, p)` вернуло больше 2 значений (в файле было больше чем 2 числа), два из них получилось положить в переменные a и b,  а остальные непонятно куда складывать.

Comment: Да, действительно, я добавил переменную C и скомпилировалось.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша программа будет верно работать только в том случае, если Вы подаёте на вход ровно два числа — в противном случае будет оставаться либо лишняя переменная, либо лишняя строка и файла.

Я предлагаю сначала все числа занести в список, а потом из этого списка вычислять сумму и произведение (первое — через `sum()`, второе — через циклы либо другие методы).

```py
fin = open('input.txt', 'r')
p = fin.read().split()
numbers = list(map(int, p)) # заносим все введённые числа в список
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
fout.write(str(sum(numbers))+'\n') # сумма чисел списка
prod = 1
for number in numbers:
    prod *= number
fout.write(str(prod)) # произведение чисел списка
fin.close()
fout.close()
```